# Relay provides power contineously

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, electronics, relay

I have set up a Pi-Zero which controls several relay switches.
The Schematic is positioned below.

```
import time
import board
import busio
import digitalio
from board import *

from datetime import date

jet_Nozzle = digitalio.DigitalInOut(D23)    #should change the pin
jet_Nozzle.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

jet_Spray_led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(D16)  #should change the pin too
jet_Spray_led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

def spray_function():
    while True:
        jet_Nozzle.value = True
        jet_Spray_led = True
        time.sleep(6)               # how long its on for... make this 5 in future.
        jet_Nozzle.value = False
        jet_Spray_led = False
        time.sleep(10)              #how long off for - make this 300 for 5 minutes off

spray_function()
```

For reasons unknown to me, the system seems to just run the dose motors 100% regardless of the status of the relay. The relay light on the Pi side flashes on/off as expected. But obviously, there is something wrong...

Initially when i first hooked up, nothing went on at all, so I'm very confused.

[image]

This is the relay board:
https://www.makerstore.com.au/product/elec-2chan-ss-relay-module/

- Spec:

  - 2 Channels
- List itemSize: 55 x 33 x 25mm (L * W * H)
- Input Power: 5V DC (160MA)
- Input control signal voltage:
- 0-2.5V state low relay ON
- 3.3-5V state high relay OFF
- Voltage Current: 12.5mA
- Trigger Voltage: 0-2.5V
- Trigger Current: 2mA
- Voltage: 5V Quiescent Current: 0mA

Comment: What is the specification of your solid state relay board?

Comment: The "schematic" is meaningless. All we are interested in is the Pi connections and specifications of the relay. If it is low level trigger and powered by 5V (like so much rubbish made for Arduino) you are likely to damage the Pi and it is unusable without additional interfacing circuitry.

Comment: Updated with details of the relay - @Millways, I'm not sure why it's meaningless as the Pi connections are specific and I assumed you'd want to see how it's wired up.  Can you please explain how/why it would damage the Pi? It's a relay, not damaging the pi is the entire point of it... What additional circuitry are you referring?

Comment: Those solid state relays may only work correctly at 240V AC with a certain load.

Comment: Load should be 240V AC according to solid state relay spec https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/307/g3mb_0609-1189645.pdf

Comment: the switched citcuit must cross zero volts for the SSR to switch off ... when switching DC, then the relay will stay turned on until the circuit is interrupted by an external switch

Comment: Most "low level trigger" devices put 5V on the GPIO, but without more detail no one can tell. The spec says "3.3-5V state high relay OFF" The Pi can NOT supply 3.3V @2mA - HIGH is >1.3V *VIH: The minimum high level voltage. (1.3V on the BCM2835)*. It is meaningless because we don't care what you are attempting to do with the SSR, although these only control AC loads.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by the comments, the issue was that the relay requires 240V load.

I was running it with 12v load -

Fixed by getting new relay...